# How can i add users to an apim gateway and restrict the users for particular operations?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

I have created an apim gateway, now i need to add some users and they only have rights to do some specific operations to the API's, like some users only have the right to execute GET requests, some users only have the right to execute POST requests etc. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Role-based access control helps that, please see the below extract from the [URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview)

**How RBAC determines if a user has access to a resource**
The following are the high-level steps that RBAC uses to determine if you have access to a resource on the management plane. This is helpful to understand if you are trying to troubleshoot an access issue.

A user (or service principal) acquires a token for Azure Resource Manager.

The token includes the user's group memberships (including transitive group memberships).

The user makes a REST API call to Azure Resource Manager with the token attached.

Azure Resource Manager retrieves all the role assignments and deny assignments that apply to the resource upon which the action is being taken.

Azure Resource Manager narrows the role assignments that apply to this user or their group and determines what roles the user has for this resource.

**Azure Resource Manager determines if the action in the API call is included in the roles the user has for this resource.**

If the user doesn’t have a role with the action at the requested scope, access is not granted. Otherwise, Azure Resource Manager checks if a deny assignment applies.

If a deny assignment applies, access is blocked. Otherwise access is granted.

Answer (score 0):

APIM runtime part does not rely on ARM RBAC. Instead APIM maintains its own user database. Scenario you describe is achievable by splitting your operations into multiple APIs, and controlling access to those APIs via subscriptions.

All that is built-in into APIM, so it's simple to setup, but may be cumbersome to maintain. If that is the case, then your next option is to use policies and policy expressions. Look at `choose` policy, it allows you to conditionally stop request processing (`return-response` policy). Of course that requires you to be able to make authorization decision purely based on what is available in request, i.e. path, headers, user id e.t.c.

I cases like this using `validate-jwt` policy is preferable since it allows you to rely on a limited set of claims in provided identity, rather than hard-coded list of user ids/names. But it does require you to have an JWT token with every request.